# Null pointer exception in While using elasticsearch XContentBuilder usage

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

We are using XContentBuilder as follows it is throwing NullPointerException

```
private int count=0;
public void outerCall(){
        XContentBuilder contentBuilder = jsonBuilder();
        contentBuilder.startObject();
        contentBuilder.field("key1", "value1");
        contentBuilder.field("key2", "value2");
        innerCall(contentBuilder, 0);
        contentBuilder.field("key3", "value3");
        contentBuilder.close();
        log.info("OUTER "+contentBuilder.string());

 }


private XContentBuilder innerCall(XContentBuilder contentBuilder, int count2) throws Exception{

    //XContentBuilder contentBuilder = jsonBuilder().startObject();

    contentBuilder.startArray("specifications");
    contentBuilder.startObject();
    contentBuilder.field("key", "value");

    if(count<2){
        innerCall(contentBuilder, count++);
    }
    else{
        contentBuilder.endObject().endArray().endObject();
        return contentBuilder;          
    }
    log.info(contentBuilder.string());
    return contentBuilder;
}
```

this is the sample code and geting NPE at
contentBuilder.field("key3", "value3");

if try to debug the code Getting NPE at 
contentBuilder.field("key", "value");

help me to resolve the issue..

Comment: Post your stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Change method code to:

```
    private XContentBuilder innerCall(XContentBuilder contentBuilder, int count2) throws Exception{

    //XContentBuilder contentBuilder = jsonBuilder().startObject();

    contentBuilder.startArray("specifications");
    contentBuilder.startObject();
    contentBuilder.field("key", "value");

    if(count<2){
        innerCall(contentBuilder, count++);
    } else {
       log.info(contentBuilder.string());
    }
    contentBuilder.endObject().endArray().endObject();
    return contentBuilder;
}
```